# Symmetric Difference of unknown number of arrays

Tags: javascript

Okay so I know there are multiple answers to this question but all of them use different approaches and I'm confused af rn.

The objective is to create a function that takes two or more arrays and returns an array of the symmetric difference of the provided arrays. The individual helper function is working fine but the code throws an error when I try to run it whole.

Here is my attempt:

```
function sym(args) {
let totalArguments = [...args];
var helper = function (arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.filter(item => arr2.indexOf(item) === -1).concat(arr2.filter(item => arr1.indexOf(item) === -1));
}
return totalArguments.reduce(helper);}
```

The input of sym([1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4]) should be [1, 4]

Comment: The `reduce` method takes another parameter after the helper : the starting value of the accumulator.

Comment: even if I add [ ] as the second argument, the error persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you're only using the first argument:

```
function sym(args) {
  let totalArguments = [...args];
```

This takes the first argument, `args`, and makes a shallow copy of the array - which doesn't accomplish anything because you aren't mutating anywhere anyway. If you wanted to accept a variable number of arguments, use argument *rest* syntax, to collect all arguments in an array:

```
function sym(...totalArguments) {
```

```js
function sym(...totalArguments) {
  var helper = function(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.filter(item => arr2.indexOf(item) === -1).concat(arr2.filter(item => arr1.indexOf(item) === -1));
  }
  return totalArguments.reduce(helper);
}
console.log(sym([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4])) // [1, 4]
console.log(sym([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [0, 1])) // [0, 4], since 1 was duplicated
```

(There's no need to provide an initial value to the reducer)

Another option whose logic will probably be clearer to read and understand would be to iterate over all arrays and reduce into an object that keeps track of the number of times each number has occurred. Then, take the entries of the object, and return an array of the keys whose values are `1`:

```js
function sym(...args) {
  const counts = args.reduce((a, arr) => {
    arr.forEach((num) => {
      a[num] = (a[num] || 0) + 1;
    });
    return a;
  }, {});
  return Object.entries(counts)
    .filter(([, count]) => count === 1)
    .map(([key]) => key);
}
console.log(sym([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4])) // [1, 4]
console.log(sym([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [0, 1])) // [0, 4], since 1 was duplicated
```

Comment: Use rest syntax instead of creating a shallow copy of the first argument